# Fullcalendar doesn't work

Tags: javascript, events, fullcalendar

I like the fullcalendar JQuery-Plugin. My calendar doesn't work. At the moment i am looking for a solution to add an event but i can't... Why ?
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: '2017-05-11',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        select: function(start, end, allDay) {
            var title = prompt("Event here: ", "New Event:");
            if (title != null) {
                calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                    {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end,
                        allDay: allDay
                    },
                    true // make the event "stick"
                );
            }
            $calendar.fullCalendar("unselect");
        },
        events: [
            {   
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2017-05-01'
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: what is this for `true // make the event "stick"` ? You can't just have true anywhere what's true ?

Comment: I find this example on the internet. That "select:.... ". I don't know what is wrong. The prompt appear but if i complete the field doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define variable calendar like below

```
var calendar =  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
```

Then it will work.